# Panzoom library: Zoom in and out while clicking the image works only for the first time

Tags: javascript, html, panzoom

I'm using Panzoom library [panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom) and would like to be able to zoom in and zoom out an image while clicking the image itself. It works. But only for the first time. I want to zoom in an image in two steps (2 clicks) and zoom out in 1 step.
I added console logs to check the scale.
When I click for the fourth time it immediately shows zoom in: 1.7 (first step) and zoom out. And nothing happens.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('img')
let panzoom = {}


panzoom = new Panzoom(img.parentElement, {
  minScale: 1,
  maxScale: 2.5,
  step: 0.5,
  // contain: "outside",
  // panzoomMouseMove: 0,
  panOnlyWhenZoomed: 1,
  cursor: 'zoom-in',
});


img.addEventListener('click', () => {
  img.style.pointer = 'zoom-out';
  panzoom.zoomIn({ animate: true })
  console.log("Zoom in: ", panzoom.getScale()) 
  if (panzoom.getScale() === 2.5) {
    img.style.cursor = 'zoom-out';
    img.addEventListener('click', () => {
      panzoom.zoomOut({ step: 1 });
      img.style.cursor = 'zoom-in';
      console.log("Zoom out: ", panzoom.getScale())
    });
  }
})
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

 .offerBox_image {
          max-width: 429px;
        }
  .offerBox_image img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@panzoom/panzoom@4.5.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>
  <div class="offerBox_image">
          <img
            data-id="1"
            class="img"
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1100x1100"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine helped me and told that because I'm using two click events they cancel each other. So I should have to have only one click event like that:

```js
img.addEventListener('click', () => {
  img.style.pointer = 'zoom-out';
  panzoom.zoomIn({ animate: true, step: 0.4 })
  console.log("Zoom in: ", panzoom.getScale()) 
  if (panzoom.getScale() === 2.5) {
    img.style.cursor = 'zoom-out';    
      panzoom.zoomOut({ step: 1 });
      img.style.cursor = 'zoom-in';
      console.log("Zoom out: ", panzoom.getScale())
 
  }
})
```